# Dispose UserControl MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, unity-container

So I am little bit stuck here, therefore I decided to ask the question in so. Maybe someone can clarify me on this and tell me what I am doing wrong...

Few words on the application:

- Our architecture is based on mvvm light and unity.
- All view model's implement IDisposable.
- Datacontext binding is defined in app.xaml, therefore views are instantiated through corresponding view model.
- View Models are instantiated through Unity.Resolve()

So far so good, now to the point I don't understand:
I have one user control with some elements inside, one of the elements has "LayoutUpdate" event declared which is handled in code behind (only for the test purposes). This calls some console output.

Afterwards I change the view (create a new view model instance) and set is as actual view in the content presenter (in main window view model). Prior to that I call dispose on the previous view model and all view models inside (recursively).

What I have noticed afterwards is that the console output still happens in the background although the view model is disposed and not visible to the user (screen).

I have tried everything to kill the usercontrol without success (unity deregister view model, etc.). Why this user control is still "alive"? Am I doing something wrong? Why this layout updated is still called although the control is not visible?

thanks help me understand this (problem).

Comment: It would be difficult to tell just from a description.  You will need to do some memory profiling to see what connection is keeping your object alive.  Most likely something is getting hooked into an event that is keeping the whole tree alive.  An application like the ANTS memory profiler is very helpful for finding leaky connections like this.  There's a 30 day trial.  Not affiliated with the company, just a satisfied user.

Comment: First, call `GC.Collect()`  (just for diaginostics) after destroying the VMs to see if that helps. The View may just be waiting for to be collected, in which case it's no rpoblem.

Comment: My guess is that you have not unregistered your eventhandler to LayoutUpdate and therefore it is still registered and will keep on executing.

Comment: @phillip I agree with you.  He doesn't mention that he unregistered the eventhandler for the control.

Comment: As long as the handler is in the code-behind of the View it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Why would it not matter ? I think it is very logical that the eventhandler is being called all the time. It should actually be unregistered before the dispose as well. Because it is not a weak event. Also the behaviour the user describes seems to point in that direction.

Comment: An eventhandler in the code-behind is a reference-to-self, it should not block collection. The strange thing is that it is still triggered though.

Comment: But the event handler is in the viewmodel.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck - that's not what the question says.

Comment: @philip the handler is in code behind not in view model. why should i unregister? If I unregister the event I dont see if the layout is still called. So I live happy beliving that everything is ok...

Comment: I am afraid i am lost with what you mean with this : ""LayoutUpdate" event declared which is handled in code behind (only for the test purposes). This calls some console output." Is this code that you have foreseen, then please show it.

Comment: It is simple code behind event LayoutUpdated="UIElement_OnLayoutUpdated" does nothing much except Console.out...
I have never encountered such practice that says one should unregister such events.